# How do I fill one column with how many times the variable in the other column has appeared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataset consisting of two variables, A and B. Variable A consists of a list of numbers. Not all numbers are different. I want to fill variable B in each row with the number N, where N is the number of times A has appeared so far.

This is the dataframe I have:

```
A      B
2101    
2101    
2102    
2102    
2102    
2103    
2104    
2104    
2104    
2104
```

Here is how I want the output to be:

```
A       B
2101    1
2101    2
2102    1
2102    2
2102    3
2103    1
2104    1
2104    2
2104    3
2104    4
```

Comment: see cumcount : `df['B']=df.groupby('A').cumcount()+1`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do that with this

```
df['B']=df.groupby('A').cumcount()+1  # +1 as the index starts with 0
```

reference : [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)